# How to re-enable "Move window to workspace X"

Tags: 16.04, gnome, workspaces

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and updated Gnome to 3.18.5 as well. 
Now if I right click on any window I only see the context option "Move to Workspace Up" or "Move to Workspace Down". 
But I'd like to have the option "Move to Workspace X". Otherwise moving a window from workspace 1 to 5 becomes a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any direct solution to this, but a workaround is to enter overview mode (tap the win/super key). There you can drag windows between workspaces on the right side of the screen. Hope this helps somewhat :) PS: this works for Ubuntu 16.10 at least.

Comment: You can also add details about keyboard shortcuts as they are much faster than any pointer method,  `Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down` to quickly move up or down a workspace